# unresloved reference to Select.from activeandroid

Tags: android, kotlin, activeandroid

i have code

```
 fun loadAllNotes() : MutableList<Note> = Select.from(Note::class.java).fetch()
```

but i have trouble with Select.from: Unresolved reference: from.
It's code by guide and it works in tutorial.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

need to use

```
import com.reactiveandroid.query.Select
```

not

```
import com.activeandroid.query.Select
```